# Low quality bluetooth audio (including lag)

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

I'm using 16.04 and Bose QuietComfort35 headphones. When using them with my phone I have no lag/delay/syncproblems what so ever, but as soon as I use them with my computer i get lag. I'm using the "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" profile in Blueman as well as in PulseAudio. The bluetooth interface is a built in chip in the computer, no idea what type but probably pretty crappy.

WiFi is disabled.

Initially I had some problems pairing over bluetooth, but installing Blueman fixed this. The firmware on the headphones are also freshly updated.

The problem is after a while when playing anything using a bit more processing power, the audio starts to stutter. The audio is then buffered up and will continue after i cancel the source. e.g. if I listen to spotify and do something in the background the audio begins to stutter. I then pause spotify and listen to stutter-free music for 1-2 seconds. Same goes for movies or any other source of sound. Youtube seems to be the worst.

When I check blueman I can clearly see that the transfer rate slows from ~41.4 KBps to ~30 KBps during stuttering and then continues at 41.4 again when paused until the audio dies out.

Can I somehow increase the package size or transfer speed? Is this the issue?

41.4 KBps seems pretty bad to me, and the audio quality reflects this, seeing as it is medium at best...